# How to use fancybox with webpack?

Tags: webpack, fancybox

I'm currently developing a webpage and started using webpack in my build process. I've managed to use slick-carrousel plugin downloaded via npm but can't make fancybox to work!

I've downloaded it via npm and imported it as stated in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancybox):

```
var $ = require("jquery");
var slick = require("slick-carousel");
var fancybox = require("fancybox")($);
```

Then in my code I try to initailize a fancybox object and nothing happens. It throws no errors at all.

```
$(".filtros__filtrar").on('click', function() {    
  $.fancybox.open({
    src  : '#tns-filtros',
    type : 'inline',
    opts : {
      smallBtn: false
    }
  });
});
```

If I do a console log of those variables I get:

```
console.log(fancybox);  ->  undefined
console.log(slick);     ->  {}
```

Which means slick module is loading correctly but not fancybox.

[Somewhere](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/integrating-jquery-chosen-with-webpack-using-imports-loader/) I read that you have to use imports-loader to make fancybox recognize jquery variables. So I downloaded it via npm and included this in my webpack.config file:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /fancybox[\/\\]dist[\/\\]js[\/\\]jquery.fancybox.cjs.js/,
      use: "imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window"
    }
  ]
}
```

But it doesn't work either.

Can someone give me a light on this subject? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the text of the error? Do you use fancybox version 3 or 2?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. That's the annoying thing. I want to use [Fancybox  3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fancyapps/fancybox) but just realized I downloaded [Fancybox 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancybox). Maybe that's part of the issue. I'll have to check about that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok. I managed to solve the problem like this.

First, I realized that I installed [Fancybox 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancybox) instead of [Fancybox 3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fancyapps/fancybox) so I uninstalled the first and installed the last (Thanks to @Mikhail Shabrikov for making me realize that!).

```
npm uninstall fancybox --save-dev
npm install @fancyapps/fancybox --save
```

Second, I dig through Fancybox original code and saw that it requires jQuery to be passed to it as `window.jQuery` and not `$` so in my requires I did this:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
window.jQuery = $;  <-- This is what do the magic!!
var slick = require("slick-carousel");
require("@fancyapps/fancybox");
```

And voila! Everything works now.

Comment: "require" was the key for me, instead of "import" - thanks!

Comment: Using `window.jQuery = $;` is unfortunately a very ugly hack. The answer from Ito Pizarro helps to get read of that line.

Comment: I'd say you should install like this `npm install @fancyapps/fancybox --save` (not --save-dev) as fancybox is to be used on the front-end and not a build-tool etc.

Comment: You're right. Fixed. Thanks @ChristofferHelgelinHald

Answer (score 2):

This is not entirely true - "I've downloaded it via npm and imported it as stated in the documentation". You do not have to assign `require('fancybox')($)` into variable, this calling returns nothing. Below - it is a snippet from [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancybox)

> var $ = require('jquery');
>
> require('fancybox')($); <------- (2)

You can check if your jQuery object has `fancybox` method with `console.log($.fancybox)`. If it returns a function, it means that you successfully import a fancybox package to your code. So you should seek the cause of the error in another place. In this case, check if the object which you passed to `$.fancybox.open` is correct. As I know, the property `src` of this object should contain an url to image or video what you want to show. Like in [this example](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/GEKgjp?editors=1010) from fancybox official site.

Comment: You are totally right Mikhail! If I check `console.log($.fancybox)` I get `ƒ (){o.open.apply(this,arguments)}` which is correct. I'll have to see what else I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fought with the same issue and found that you can have [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) automatically load modules — making them available to the various plugins as needed — via [`ProvidePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) right in the `webpack.config`. Webpack's [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) covers the naked `$` or `jQuery` instances…

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin( {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        } )
    ]
};
```

But, as [metaskopia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359784/metaskopia) found, Fancybox wants `window.jQuery`. To that end, the following worked:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin( {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        } )
    ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks @ItoPizarro that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my setup

### 1) Install Fancybox NPM

```
npm install @fancyapps/fancybox --save-dev
```

### 2) Initialize Fancybox

```
// Require jQuery (Fancybox dependency)
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

// Fancybox
const fancybox = require('@fancyapps/fancybox');
// Fancybox Stylesheet
const fancyboxCSS = require('!style!css!@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css');
```

### 3) Select what elements to open with Fancybox

To attach Fancybox to the images, you need to add the attribute `[data-fancybox="optional-gallary-identifier"]` to the element.

You can do this manually via HTML or with jQuery. Here are 2 ways you can do this with jQuery.

**To open all images with Fancybox (`a > img`)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox a > img').parent().attr('data-fancybox');
});
```

**To group images into galleries by .lightbox wrapper**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('a > img').parent().attr('data-fancybox', 'group-' + i);
  });
});
```

If you have any dynamically loaded content, i.e. ajax, you'll need to apply the `data-fancybox` attribute to the dynamically loaded elements.